# Which law rules polygraphs inadmissible in UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, criminal-law, england-and-wales, civil-law, common-law

Where does it say that polygraph tests (lie detector tests) are inadmissible under law in England and Wales?

I am mostly interested in their usage being disallowed for criminal (both Magistrates' Court and Crown Court) and civil matters. However, if they were allowed elsewhere, such as for employment tribunals, that would be useful knowledge.

Comment: Are we trying to prove a negative here? Would it be sufficient that no court has ruled them  admissible?

Comment: I was told that they are not allowed. Where is proof that they are allowed or not allowed?

Comment: ... but the question asks whether they're disallowed, which is different to "not allowed". If they're disallowed, there will be a specific record (statute or precedent), while if they're not allowed there will be no statute or precedent to permit their use.

Answer (score 2):

[canada](/questions/tagged/canada)

See *R. v. Béland*, [[1987] 2 S.C.R. 398](https://www.canlii.org/en/ca/scc/doc/1987/1987canlii27/1987canlii27.html):

> It is therefore my opinion that evidence of the results of a polygraph examination would clearly offend the rule against the admission of past or out‑of‑court statements by a witness. All of the considerations upon which the rule is based are as applicable to polygraph evidence as to other statements. The repetition of statements by another witness adds nothing to their weight and reliability. The ultimate decision as to the truth or falsity of the evidence of a witness must rest upon the exercise of the judgment of the trier of fact. This is as true of evidence of polygraph tests as of any other evidence. In the last analysis, the trier of fact must reach its conclusion on the basis of the evidence given by a human being in court. The evidence of the polygraph operator if heard by the trier of fact adds nothing to the earlier statement of the witness which is sought to be supported.
>
> ...
>
> It was also argued that the polygraph evidence was receivable as expert evidence. The polygraph operator, as an expert, was trained and qualified to give his opinion as to the veracity of the witness, based solely on his interpretation of the significance of the responses made by the witness to the questions put on the examination.
>
> ...
>
> Here, the sole issue upon which the polygraph evidence is adduced is the credibility of the accused, an issue well within the experience of judges and juries and one in which no expert evidence is required. It is a basic tenet of our legal system that judges and juries are capable of assessing credibility and reliability of evidence.

[Another answer](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/94502/46948) says:

> The real problem with polygrapher's opinions however (like policeman's opinions), is that they simply aren't reliable enough.

But lack of reliability was not part of the Supreme Court's legal reasoning for rejecting the use of polygraph evidence in court.

Answer (score 0):

What I say during a lie detector test might be considered a valid testimony. But the point of a lie detector test is to identify lies and state that my testimony is not true. "I didn't kill my wife" is valid testimony. That *might* be considered in court unless it is considered hearsay. The lie detector test saying "he lied, therefore he killed his wife" is not valid testimony. I never said "I killed my wife", so it's not valid testimony.

You would *at least* have to have an expert witness who is willing to testify that this machine can beyond a reasonable doubt detect that I am lying, and you won't find that expert witness.

Answer (score -2):

The same laws that say you can't admit tea-leaf readings, Ouija board results, or the opinions of spiritual mediums.

Lots of people like to imagine a polygraph machine as something that tells truth from falsehood - like the cartoon representation with red and green lights, buzzers and bells.

In reality, the machine itself simply measures and graphs a number of physiological parameters like breathing rate, sweat rate, and so on. Hence the name, polygraph - it roughly means "multiple measurements".

The actual polygraph process does not just consist of the machine, but of a "polygrapher", a person who formulates a series of questions, puts them to the subject, and then analyses and interprets the physiological behaviour of the subject in response to those questions.

Polygraphers accept that no specific reading on the machine implies truth or falsehood.

The role the graphing machine plays is not in arriving at a verdict about truth or falsehood, but merely in supplying the polygrapher with certain kinds of physiological information about the subject that would be difficult to discern directly by their own eye.

Through experience and repeated exposure, polygraphers argue that they are able to intuitively discern certain relationships and patterns in the readings, and arrive at a personal judgment as to whether they think someone is telling the truth or not.

They aren't (as a professional collective) able to adduce or describe the exact effect of their experience upon their judgments, or articulate a consistent process by which they arrive at a particular judgment. Rather, they offer themselves as a black box, in the reliability of which the courts must simply trust.

Properly, these results would not be called "polygraph tests" at all, they would be called "polygrapher's opinions".

The problem is that this is exactly what judges and juries are supposed to be doing - and indeed in a more wholesome way.

The polygrapher effectively seeks to usurp the role of judge and jury, by saying that they don't need to analyse the evidence or formulate an opinion, because the polygrapher has already done so.

That is one reason polygrapher's opinions are not welcome in court, because they seek to assert that they have already arrived at the verdict that the court process is supposed to deliver at its conclusion.

It is really not very different from a policeman insisting to a court that his gut feeling is that a suspect is guilty/innocent, and expecting that to be admitted under the auspices of scientific evidence.

The only difference is that the policeman uses his eyes and ears directly to judge the subject, whereas the polygrapher has the additional theatre of a special machine.

The real problem with polygrapher's opinions however (like policeman's opinions), is that they simply aren't reliable enough. I once heard a study had found a 70% reliability for yes/no questions. That sounds somewhat compelling to the average person, until noting that a simple coin toss is 50% reliable on yes/no questions.

So a plain coin toss is wrong only half the time on average, and a so-called "lie detector" still wrong more than a quarter of the time on average.

It's true that polygraphers may be better than chance, but so is the court process - at least insofar as we believe that far fewer than one quarter of convicted criminals are wrongly convicted. We accept miscarriages of justice do occur, but not as many as one quarter of all cases.

Another problem is that the courts often aren't dealing with the "average" person - the average person generally not being a habitual liar, a fantasist, or a determined career criminal.

Once you're dealing with an adverse selection of people who might be shameless liars, might even have convinced themselves of a lie, and who have the motive and opportunity to rehearse easy and artful lying, the reliability must drop - and in fact, knowing polygraphy is being used routinely, becomes an opportunity for good liars to game the court process.

Polygraphy is basically the modern-day phrenology in criminal justice. It's objective in that it seeks to measure and analyse real features about a subject, but is complete hokum in the robustness of the connection it seeks to draw between those measurements and some other supposed fact.

These are essentially the reasons why a court uses it's general power to exclude such "evidence".

Comment: When you check your blood pressure, every nurse knows the procedure makes you nervous and your blood pressure shoots up. You ask me @did you kill your wife”. Of course I react.

Comment: @gnasher729, exactly so. The tenet of polygraphy is that lying is supposed to correspond with stress, tension, or mental workload. But so do many truthful answers, especially if you're on trial over a particular question (and usually a subject will know what they're accused of, and recognise the connection of certain questions, before being examined by a polygrapher). These tense truth-tellers are basically the counterparts of the relaxed liars, in terms of those who invalidate the assumptions of polygraphy.